# Blackberry compatibility issues

Tags: blackberry

Hi i started blackberry application development for 5.0 operating system.I just want to ask whether these apps would also run on operating system 6.0 as i heard that blackberry is forward compatible.

Comment: yes you are right `BlackBerry` dont support backward compatibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you develop for BB os 5.0 it will work on os5.0 upwards, which are os 5.0,os6.0 , os7.0 etc. It will not work in pre os5.0 which are like os 4.5 ,os 4.6 etc